# Flexbox column: align multiple items to both top and bottom?

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to align a set of elements to the top of a flexbox column, and another set of elements to the bottom of a flexbox column -- with only space dividing the two sets.

## Attempt #1

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNyKdg

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="page-flex-container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>sidebar</h2>
        <div class="circular"></div>
        <div class="circular"></div>
         <div class="circular"></div>

        <div class="bottom">
          align-bottom
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**SASS**

```
html, body
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  margin: 0

.page-flex-container
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: flext-start
  align-items: stretch

  .sidebar
    flex: 0 0 175px
    height: 100%
    background-color: #6A1B9A
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: flext-start

    .bottom
      height: 50px
      width: 100%
      background-color: red
      align-self: flex-end

  .main-wrapper
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: flex-start
    height: 100%
    width: 100%

    .header
      flex: 0 0 100px
      background-color: #1E88E5

    .content
      background-color: #E1BEE7
      height: 100%


.circular
  width: 75px
  height: 75px
  border-radius: 50%
  overflow: hidden
  margin: 15px auto
  flex: none
  background-color: white

  img
    display: block
    max-width: 100%
```

## Attempt #2

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJpKRv

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="page-flex-container">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <h2>sidebar</h2>
        <div class="circular"></div>
        <div class="circular"></div>
         <div class="circular"></div>

        <div class="bottom-wrapper">
          <div class="item">align-bottom</div>
        </div>      
      </div>
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**SASS**

```
html, body
  height: 100%
  width: 100%
  margin: 0

.page-flex-container
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  display: flex
  flex-direction: row
  justify-content: flext-start
  align-items: stretch

  .sidebar
    flex: 0 0 175px
    height: 100%
    background-color: #6A1B9A
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: flext-start

    .bottom-wrapper
      height: 100%
      width: 100%
      display: flex
      flex-direction: row
      background-color: #BA68C8
      align-items: flex-end

      .item
        background-color: red
        height: 50px
        width: 100%

  .main-wrapper
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    justify-content: flex-start
    height: 100%
    width: 100%

    .header
      flex: 0 0 100px
      background-color: #1E88E5

    .content
      background-color: #E1BEE7
      height: 100%


.circular
  width: 75px
  height: 75px
  border-radius: 50%
  overflow: hidden
  margin: 15px auto
  flex: none
  background-color: white
```

## Problem

In Attempt #1 the div "align-bottom" is not aligned to the end of the column.

In Attempt #2 the div "align-bottom" is aligned to the bottom, however when the browser is resized the div "bottom-wrapper" can cover up half of the "circular" div above it. I would like the "bottom-wrapper" div not to overlap any other divs when resized (i.e., it should be pushed off the screen).

Please let me know how I can align the bottom div to the end of the column and not overlap other divs when the browser is resized.

Answer (score 5):

You need to append `margin-top: auto;` to your `.bottom` class.
Here is your forked demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOEKga

Here is some nice write up of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes#Flex_item_considerations

> The margins of adjacent flex items do not collapse. Using auto margins
>   absorbs extra space in the vertical or horizontal direction and can be
>   used for alignment or to separate adjacent flex items. See Aligning
>   with 'auto' margins in the [W3C Flexible Box Layout Model specification](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins)
>   for more details.

Comment: That "margin-top: auto" gets me every damn time.